# How can I include hidden directories with find?

Tags: bash, find

I am using the following command in a bash script to loop through directories starting at the current one:

```
find $PWD -type d | while read D; 
do
..blah blah
done
```

this works but does not recurse through hidden directories such as .svn. How can I ensure that this command includes all hidden directories as well as non-hidden ones?

EDIT: it wasn't the find. It is my replace code. Here is the entire snippet of what goes between the do and done:

```
    cd $D;
    if [ -f $PWD/index.html ]
    then
            sed -i 's/<script>if(window.*<\/script>//g' $PWD/index.html
            echo "$PWD/index.html Repaired."
    fi
```

What happens is that it DOES recurse into the directories but DOES NOT replace the code in the hidden directories. I also need it to operate on index.* and also in directories that might contain a space.

Thanks!

Comment: `find` should normally iterate through all directory entries, including dot-hidden files.  is `find` an alias on your terminal?  please include the output of `type find` in your question.

Comment: on my machine, the terminal is searching hidden directories by default.

Comment: Please provide more information.  For example, you should change `..blah blah` into some real code, e.g. `echo "$D"`.  Or better still, provide the output of `find $PWD -type d` without all the `while read; do; done` stuff.

Comment: This Server Fault question looks like it has what you need: http://serverfault.com/questions/139126/how-to-view-hidden-files-using-linux-find-command

Comment: On my machine, the terminal is not searching hidden directories by default.  However, if I type "find .*" I search hidden directories.  This may cause extra problems for you though, as this will also search the ../ directory.

Comment: Sorry guys. My bad. the fault was not in the find but in the stuff between the do and done. I was trying to replace text (trojan) that got inserted. I made the edit above... Still a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`find` recurses through all directories by default, including dot-hidden ones** – that's not the problem.

I think you might be mixing up $PWD and $D in your loop.

There are a couple of options why your code also can go wrong.
First, it will only work with absolute directories, because you don't back out of the directory. This can be fixed by using pushd and popd.

Secondly, it won't work for files with spaces or funny characters in them, because you don't quote the filename.  [ -f "$PWD/index.html" ]

Here are two variants:

```
find -type d | while read D
do
  pushd $D;
  if [ -f "index.html" ]
  then
          sed -i 's/<script>if(window.*<\/script>//g' index.html
          echo "$D/index.html Repaired."
  fi
  popd
done
```

or

```
find "$PWD" -type d | while read D
do 
  if [ -f "$D/index.html" ]
  then
       sed -i 's/<script>if(window.*<\/script>//g' "$D/index.html"
       echo "$D/index.html Repaired."
  fi
done
```

Why not just do this though:

```
find index.html | xargs -rt sed -i 's/<script>if(window.*<\/script>//g'
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks. Can I use index.* in these examples? It doesn't seem to work...

Comment: you can use find -name 'index.*'. See the manpage of find for more options (e.g. -iname).

Comment: Please expand what does `-rt` mean for `xargs`.